# Dynamic update file name mssql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
create table #sample(id varchar(100), set_type varchar(100) ,[group] int, Name varchar(100))
insert into #sample(id,set_type,[group])
select '12','Red',1
union all 
select '2346','Red',1
union all 
select '1235','Green',1
union all 
select '12890','Green',1
union all 
select '1208','Green',1
union all 
select '1234','Green',1
union all 
select '908472','Green',2
union all 
select '7958326','Blue',1
```

I need to Dynamically update 'Name' column of table #sample  , so that i should get below desire result

```
Desire result : 

insert into #sample(id,set_type,[group],Name)
select '12','Red',1,'red_1_2_25012018'
union all 
select '2346','Red',1,'red_1_2_25012018'
union all 
select '1235','Green',1,'Green_1_2_25012018'
union all 
select '12890','Green',1,'Green_1_2_25012018'
union all 
select '1208','Green',1,'Green_3_4_25012018'
union all 
select '1234','Green',1,'Green_3_4_25012018'
union all 
select '908472','Green',2,'Green_5_5_25012018'
union all 
select '7958326','Blue',1,'Blue_1_1_25012018'
```

Logic for updating   'name' column:

1. 2 ID should have  one name eg: ID = 12 & 2346 are with 'Name' = red_1_2_25012018 ,

Take set_type=  Green  : 'Name' =  Green_1_2_25012018(Id: 1235 & 12890 ) and  'Name' = Green_3_4_25012018(ID : 1208 & 1234)

but ID: 908472 left alone as  1
record  so 'Name' = Green_5_5_25012018  Blue has only 1 record so
'name' = Blue_1_1_25012018

2. 25012018 -- DATEMONTHYEAR

So, i wanted to do this UPDATE 'name' column in set based like cte ext , because i have to update more than millions of records.

Comment: You could define your column as computed, but the logic of your 1_2, 3_4, 5_5 is not clear

Comment: Do you mean  Green_1_2_25012018,Green_3_4_25012018,Green_5_5_25012018 ?

Comment: These are file names I have to update. Green has 5 ID , so 2 ID in 1 file that is why  (Green_1_2_25012018) 1_2 , 3_4 and 5_5(only 1 record left )